# spring-data-mongodb document design options - array vs dynamic field (i.e. map)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am designing a document structure and use spring-data-mongodb to access it. The document structure is to store device profile.  Each device contains modules of different types. The device can contains multiple modules of the same type. Module types are dynamic as new type of modules are created sometimes.

Please note: I try not to write custom queries to avoid boilerplate code.  But, some custom queries should be fine.

I come out with two designs:

the first one use dynamic field (i.e. map). Semantics is better but seems harder to query/update using spring-data-mongodb.

```
{
deviceId: "12345",
instanceTypeMap: {
    "type1": {
        moduleMap: {
            "1": {field1: "value",field2: "value"},
            "2": {field1: "value",field2: "value"}
        }
    },
    "type2": {
        moduleMap: {
            "30": {fielda: "value",fieldb: "value"},
            "45": {fielda: "value",fieldb: "value"}
        }
    }
}
```

the second one use array and query/update seems more in-line with spring-data-mongodb.

```
{
deviceId: "12345",
allInstances: [
    {
        type: 1,
        modules: [
            {
                id: 1,
                field1: "value",
                field2: "value"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                field1: "value",
                field2: "value"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        type: 2,
        modules: [
            {
                id: 30,
                fielda: "value",
                fieldb: "value"
            },
            {
                id: 45,
                fielda: "value",
                fieldb: "value"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I am inclined to use array. Is it better to use array instead of dynamic field with spring-data-mongodb. I did some search on-line and found people mentioned that query for key (i.e. in map) is not as easy in spring-data-mongodb. Is that a correct statement?  Do I miss anything?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the design as below.  I use one device-instance-type per document. Because, in some scenario, 
updates are done on many modules of the same instance type. Those updates can be aggregated as just one database update.
The redundant "moduleId" field is also added for query purpose.

```
{
deviceId: "12345",
instanceTypeId: "type1",
moduleMap: {
    "1": {
        moduleId: "1",
        field1: "value",
        field2: "value"
    },
    "2": {
        moduleId: "2",
        field1: "value",
        field2: "value"
    }
}
```

}

Now, I can use spring-data-mongodb's query:

```
findByDeviceId("12345");
findByDeviceIdAndInstanceTypeId("12345","type1");
findByDeviceIdAndInstanceTypeIdAndModuleMapModuleId("12345","type1","1");
```